# How to copy all .dll dependencies into .exe folder automatically on windows?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, dll, exe

I am building a C++ project on windows, which using some third-party libraries like OpenCV.

I want to copy all my .exe's dll dependencies into its folder automatically.

How can I achieve this. Can I use visual studio to achieve this?

I am looking for someone to help me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The pedeps project (https://github.com/brechtsanders/pedeps) has a command line tool (copypedeps) for copying your .exe (or .dll) file(s) along with all the files it depends on. It has a `-r` command line parameter to copy dependencies recursively.